# Crashes with UITabBar.appearance().barStyle in swift5

Tags: ios, swift, background-color, uitabbar

I implemented a "dark mode"  and I need to change the TabBar style from default to dark and the opposite.

My app crashed !

what should I do ?

> 2019-08-28 21:42:57.276131+0200 Score[1817:344811] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Bar
>   style not supported by UITabBar. Supported bar styles are
>   UIBarStyleDefault and UIBarStyleBlack'
>            *** First throw call stack:
>            (0x19ef4aab8 0x19e14fd00 0x19ee502f4 0x1cbbd5f08 0x19ef52414 0x19ee4d0bc 0x1cbfb610c 0x1cc7f9e44 0x1cbfb6098 0x1cbfb03b8
>   0x1cbfaf7d8 0x1cc822ee4 0x1cc822e54 0x1cbbd8790 0x1cc822d58
>   0x1cc822174 0x1cbbda498 0x1cc821edc 0x1cc8152ac 0x1cc815170
>   0x1cc824d20 0x1cc3ac68c 0x1cc3acab0 0x1cc3bd80c 0x1cc36e090
>   0x1cc3739fc 0x1cbc05e04 0x1cbc0e7e0 0x1cbc05a6c 0x1cbc06388
>   0x1cbc045d0 0x1cbc0428c 0x1cbc08fbc 0x1cbc09e14 0x1cbc08e70
>   0x1cbc0de60 0x1cc371f38 0x1cbf54650 0x1a190dfd0 0x1a191831c
>   0x1a1917a6c 0x1004f477c 0x1004f833c 0x1a194b18c 0x1a194ae08
>   0x1a194b404 0x19eedab54 0x19eedaad0 0x19eeda38c 0x19eed5060
>   0x19eed4964 0x1a1115d8c 0x1cc375758 0x1000a96ec 0x19e990fd8)
>            libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
enum Theme: Int {
case Light, Dark

var barStyle: UIBarStyle {
    switch self {
    case .Light:
        return .default
    case .Dark:
        return .blackTranslucent
    }
}
//...
}

class ThemeManager {
static func applyTheme(theme: Theme) {
    if(theme == .Dark){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "darkMode")
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "darkMode")
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    let sharedApplication = UIApplication.shared
    sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.tintColor = theme.buttonColor

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = theme.barStyle
    UITabBar.appearance().barStyle = theme.barStyle

    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = theme.labelColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = theme.labelColor

    //...

}
}
```

Comment: What iOS version are you running your app on?

Comment: i'm running on the latest version iOS 12.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The exception’s reason for termination states:

> Supported bar styles are UIBarStyleDefault and ***UIBarStyleBlack***

So it appears that all we have to do is modify `barStyle` to:

```swift
var barStyle: UIBarStyle {
    switch self {
    case .Light:
        return .default
    case .Dark:
        return .black
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks. That's works. I have a strange 'reaction'. I mean I have a black TabBar in Light mode, and a clear one in Dark mode. If I swap the value, I still have a black TabBar in Light mode and a black one in Dark mode.

Comment: Moreover, How to reload the TabBar style without restarting the app ?

Comment: I would encourage you to read through Apple's [Supporting Dark Mode in Your Interface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface).

Then see [`appearance(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance/1615007-appearance) & [`init(userInterfaceStyle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/1651062-init).